# Is there an alternative to justifying the list items so that the hover link functionality doesn't span across the entire width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to use only icons in my navbar and I've succeeded in justifying the list items using:

```
.navbar-nav {
  .nav-justified;
}
```

The icons only take up approximately 30 pixels, but the hover link functionality spans way beyond the actual icons. I was wondering if there was an alternative method of justifying the list items across the width of the browser while limiting the hover link functionality to the width of each icon.

Comment: The example looks a bit like CSS, but it isn't. Also, can you show the HTML, preferably as a JSFiddle or something.

Comment: I'm using LESS so I'm not sure how to exactly show it as a JSFiddle but here's my HTML+LESS: http://jsfiddle.net/L5MzL/

Comment: The Bootstrap CSS seems to change the display type of the `a` from inline to block, so it takes up the entire width of its parent (the `li`). So all you need to do is change it back with `a {display:inline}`. I updated your fiddle - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5MzL/3/) - but I needed to compile the CSS, because JSFiddle doesn't handle LESS.

Comment: Oh my goodness. So simple but I never thought of it. You're the best! Thank you!